# Advice on specific Web Based 3D Game Development

Tags: javascript, three.js, webgl, game-physics, conceptual

I'm relatively new to HTML and Javascript, but I'm knee deep in the Udacity interactive 3D course and have gotten my hands dirty with some three.js + WebGL. And I've been able to make and somewhat understand this:
http://goo.gl/UPWKKL
So far.(having a hard time understanding the API and getting cannon.js and really any interesting mechanics to work, any advice for learning APIs like threejs?)

I was wondering if anyone could provide any input for someone whose end goal is to make a game that is somewhat like a demi-version of: REZ, Exteel, Armored Core or Zone of The Enders versus mode.

My goal is implementing: rail shooting(w/ cannon.js?), health bars, NPC boss battles with different stages, animated movements, a cross-hair, level bounds, concepts of upgrades to a character.
To be really specific, a 5 level game with PointerLockControl + shooting interface, where each level pass requires bringing a boss' health bar down to zero.  The enemy would have a vulnerable mesh area where if bullet objects hit it, it'd trigger a collision event where its health decreased.  If health<= 25 it speeds up and becomes harder to kill.  After its death the screen blacks out and restarts with a new boss and so on.  I'd want to put in victory screens, failure screens and if possible, cut scenes where I guess I'd disable user control and enable some kind of path cinematic camera.  And preferrably for this to all be in the browser like Quake, BUT if something like this isn't possible, I'd try something else.

Sorry if this question is too broad or weird, I want to work on video games for a living, I will appreciate any feedback I get, **I just want to know if someone more experienced can look at what kind of game I want to make and recommend some up to date material or helpful sites.**

Currently I'm working with webGL and threejs, I've looked into Unity3D but I can't develop that on my Linux machine.  *Far FARR down the line I'd like make full blown games in C++.*

Answer (score 0):

Design as specifically as possible, because then you will have lots of small tasks whose role in the greater whole is known. Then if you don't know what to do on any given day, just look at your design, your map, and pick a piece that you can do that day.

Sorry if this answer is not specific to WebGL but you have asked broadly.

Comment: not at all sir, yeah I know it was broad, thank you this was good.